# PHP - how to search in encrypted data in DB

Tags: php, database, search, encryption

I have a Users table in my MySQL database and the user details (email, name, address, etc) are encrypted using the PHP openssl_encrypt() function.

This all works fine, and now I want to include a page in the site Admin that allows the administrator to search for a particular user. The admin will start typing the first letters of the user's name or email address in a search box and that would propose a list of users that would filter down as they type.

I would normally do this with a simple AJAX call each time a letter is entered which would query the database. But how can I do this if the names (or maybe email addresses) have to be decrypted?

Also, is there a way of selecting them in alphabetical order if they are encrypted?

Any suggestions you have would be welcome.

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to perform a LIKE search with encrypted data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38184167/how-to-perform-a-like-search-with-encrypted-data)

Comment: Or this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36655190/best-way-to-search-encrypted-data-inside-mysql

Comment: Or this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46659528/search-filter-on-encrypted-data-in-mysql

Comment: Thanks for posting those links, though I'm not sure there is a solution in there. I don't know anything about blind indexes, so I'll have a look at that. Thank you.